# Getting nested group members via Get-ADObject

Tags: powershell

I have Universal group with distribution scope and there are contacts and groups and users which are members of this DL. I am trying to below command but not getting details of groups or users with powershell. Those groups have groups nested within them that contain users.

How can i export nested group members and users from distribution group from AD Powershell cmdlet?

Example:
Group A
Members = asmith(Contact), jbloggs,Group B (member = kbrown)

Here is my code :

```
$memberof=get-adgroup -Filter "Name -like 'IT*'" |select -expandproperty distinguishedname

#$distinguishedName = $memberof -replace "(CN=)(.*?),.*",'$2'

foreach ($memberof1 in $memberof) { 

$distinguishedName = $memberof1 -replace "(CN=)(.*?),.*",'$2'

Get-ADObject -Filter 'memberof -eq $memberof1 -and (objectClass -eq "user" -or ObjectClass -eq "contact" -or objectclass -eq "group")' -properties *|select name | Export-csv -Path "C:\temp\$distinguishedName.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either use `Get-ADGroupMember` with the `-Recursive` parameter switch:

```
$AllMembers = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'IT*'" |Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive
```

or use the [special in-chain operator in an LDAP query filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/search-filter-syntax#operators) for the `memberOf` attribute:

```
$GroupDN = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'IT*'" |Select -Expand DistinguishedName
$AllMembers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$GroupDN)"
```